# What is client side in Object Oriented Programming?

Tags: oop

I have been hearing this word "Client Side" whenever I read book or while listening to my trainer when he teaches Object oriented programming concepts. What does exactly it mean? Can anybody help me providing an answer with example? 
Answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client-server describes an application architecture in which the client requests an action or service from the provider of service, the server. For e.g. browser is the client of a web server. Now the client and server can be co-located within the same process or within the same computer or they can be running on different computers.

Answer (score 6):

"Client side" just means "from the perspective of the user of the object", i.e. the people who are going to be using the interface, as opposed to the implementors.

Comment: Thank you Carnegie.. so, its just the user of our product right?

Comment: What you exactly meant by "user of the object"? Object is just a instance of the class right??  I have to confess that I am a newbie and it will be very helpful if you guys explain about what exactly object is?

Comment: he is not referring to *that* kind of object. In ithis context, it's an application.

Comment: @Jeevarajan if he's talking about Object Oriented design, then probably yes, when he says "client" he's talking about the user of the interface of a class through an instance of the class ('object').

Comment: Thank you guys. :) I had been confusing my self with this thing. Now I can understand what client in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Client side vs. server side:

Client side programs/applications are typically "regular" computer programs, like a web browser, a game, a text editor, etc. In network programming, and that's more often, it refers to one of the peer computer programs that communicate with the server.

The counterpart of client side is server side; server applications are typically not directly utilized by the users, and due to this fact, some special considerations shall be made while making server(-side) applications. For example, there are typically some differences in programming languages, such as JavaScript and PHP.